# Is performance feedback on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

Say we make a recording of a piece on an instrument. Are we allowed to display that recording here and ask for feedback on how well we played the piece?

Comment: Related : http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/221/review-comment-on-this-piece-i-wrote